# How do I put an array into an SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following php code getting a list of numbers from a Database:

```
  $current_product_id = "SELECT `product_id`,`category_id` FROM `oc_product_to_category` WHERE `product_id`='$product_id' ";   
  $current_product_ids = mysql_query($current_product_id); 

  $current_product_cat_ids='';

  while($current_product_cat_id = mysql_fetch_array($current_product_ids)){
$current_product_cat_ids.=$current_product_cat_id['category_id'].',';
}
  echo $current_product_cat_ids;
```

The code echos something like this: `84,109,140,146,151,152,`

I would like to now take each of those numbers and somehow use them in another SQL query kinda like this:

```
$parent_category_ids = "SELECT `category_id`,`path_id` FROM `oc_category_path` WHERE `category_id`='84,109,140,146,151,152'"
```

So I can put the values into another SQL Query. Any ideas how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies! Every answer was correct! I really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the IN clause and the same variable:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `category_id`,`path_id` FROM `oc_category_path` WHERE `category_id` IN (" . rtrim($current_product_cat_ids, ',') . ")");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL provides the `IN` operator for matching a list of values.

```
SELECT `category_id`,`path_id`
FROM `oc_category_path`
WHERE `category_id` IN (84,109,140,146,151,152)
```

If the values come from a table, a subquery is an especially useful technique;

```
SELECT `category_id`,`path_id`
FROM `oc_category_path`
WHERE `category_id` IN (SELECT `cat_id` FROM cat_table WHERE active=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You can use MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET()` or `IN()`:

```
$parent_category_ids = "SELECT `category_id`,`path_id` FROM `oc_category_path` 
    WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(`category_id`, '84,109,140,146,151,152')"
```

Or `IN()`:

```
$parent_category_ids = "SELECT `category_id`,`path_id` FROM `oc_category_path` 
    WHERE `category_id` IN(84,109,140,146,151,152)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   `category_id`
 , `path_id`
FROM `oc_category_path`
WHERE `category_id` IN(84,109,140,146,151,152)
```

OR:

```
SELECT 
   `category_id`
 , `path_id`
FROM `oc_category_path`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`category_id`, '84,109,140,146,151,152')
```

The first has no quotes, the second has quotes around the string that contains the comma-delimited list.